# Export material to Unreal Engine 4.13

Tags: export

I use http://www.manuelbastioni.com/ addon to create characters and I don't get materials when I import in Unreal Engine 4.13.
I am beginner user in Blender and Unreal Engine and I searched the solution how can I export to Unreal Engine that all material will imported in Unreal Engine.

I found that I must use UV things and reproduce colors and after save as png file.
But, there is no way to export materials in fbx without change something?

There is no compatible versions? For example blender 2.70 and unreal engine 4.11 or something like that?

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Blender Render? I've had trouble exporting materials from Blender using Cycles, but Blender Render seems to work fine. (I'm on Unreal 4.14 and Blender 2.76. But I don't believe it matters)

Answer (score 1):

Maximum that you can import - textures with the materials slot and UE can make simple material with this textures for you.

but complicated material with masks, additional color and math you should create in UE by null )