# How to Export 3D Model with current materials

Tags: shaders

How would I go about exporting my 3D model and including the shaders I've made and have applied to the objects?

Edit: I've spent a lot of time working on a 3D model which uses shaders for materials, I would like to know how I can now export this model with the materials so I can import it into another program and it be pretextured

Comment: Impossible in general. Add specifics, an example and your target application to your question so we can find a way around that.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15955/materials-and-exporting-to-different-formats/15958 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63557/export-material-to-unreal-engine-4-13